# Magento 2 Category Url not working after migration from magento 1

Tags: category, magento-2.1.3

I have a problem with my magento 2 site. this site was originally migrated from magento 1. now my problem is that. the original url is not working for example:

Instead of this one: site.com/products it will result to

```
site.com/catalog/category/view/s/products/id/3/
```

which is the first url will result to 404 not found.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have data in url_rewrite table where entity_type=category. Check https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool.
2. http://example.com/catalog/category/view/id/ should work if the category exists.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in the table **url_rewrite** whether there is **entity_type = category** with **entity_id = 3**